# Firestore document creation fails without an error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

**Edit3:** Okay, it seems like it's an issue with Firebase, someone else tweeted about having the same issue. I also contacted support.

A piece of Swift code that handles creating documents suddenly stopped working. No errors are thrown, Firebase doesn't complain in the log and I can verify from the console that the document is not created, I can verify that the device has a healthy internet connection. I also disabled offline persistence for Firebase just to be sure.

When I try debugging it, the debugger jumps straight over the block that handles errors or successes, never running it (i.e. never finishing the Firestore request?).

Here is the code

```
    func createConversation(){
    let conversation : [String : Any] = ["owners" : [
        UserProfile().getProfile().uid!],
                                         "seeking" : true,
                                         "timestamp" : Timestamp(date: Date())
    ]

    var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
    ref = DB().firestore().collection("Conversations").addDocument(data: conversation){ err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error creating a convo: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Conversation created with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
            StateMachine().action(a: .seekingStarted(ref!.documentID))


        }
        print("Conversation Creation finished")
    }
    let documentID = ref?.documentID
    print(ref.debugDescription)

}
```

I'm not sure how to approach this issue, any ideas?

**Edit:** Okay, the issue is not limited to this block of code, it looks like Firebase is not communicating with the servers. I've waited for more than 5min for the addDocument to return(with error or success) but that never happened.

I noticed that at the initiation of the App BoringSSL complains a bit but this is not new and I don't have problems with the other Firebase services, they work just fine - reading and creating data with no problems.

[image: BoringSSL complains]

**Edit2:**  Apparently I can fetch collections and documents from Firestore, the issue seems to be limited to document/collection creation.

Answer (score 0):

The document creation operation takes a little time, if you place the breakpoint inside the asynchronus completion block you will surely get an error or success.

Comment: The thing is, I've waited quite a bit, nothing ever happens. Google reports that Firebase is healthy, if it's a connection issue then it affects only Firebase since I have no problems with the Realtime Database.

Comment: remove all the breakpoints and just place one breakpoint inside the async block and see what happens

Comment: Waited for 5min, nothing happened, BTW the issue seems to be not insulated to this - it looks like Firestore SDK is not communicating with the servers(No issues with the other Firebase products) and fails to fail with a nice error. Any idea how to make it fail if can't connect?

Comment: try something else like fetching data from firestore, see if it works.

Comment: Tried it, it works when reading a document once.  It looks like there is an issue with Firestore realtime updates. I think I will create a help request with Google, in case they are not aware. Thanks.